# multipath -ll not showing any output

Tags: centos

This is my Centos 7. I moved it from one location to another, local support guy added correct cables to present SAN disks to server, but I don't see any output in multipath.
Server was rebooted and mulipath service is runing, though complaining about sdc

```
    [root@centos-app23 ~]# lsblk --fs
NAME            FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda
└─sda1          ext3              7a8015e1-e147-40ae-b5ac-da2134c6788a   /boot
sdb
├─sdb1          ext3              7664e2be-eafe-40dd-9f67-afbdab685d12
└─sdb2          LVM2_member       uoanJQ-TF4J-uNOz-5Q4R-7qfV-ThHC-5WU6ok
sdc
├─sdc1          ext3              7664e2be-eafe-40dd-9f67-afbdab685d12
└─sdc2          LVM2_member       uoanJQ-TF4J-uNOz-5Q4R-7qfV-ThHC-5WU6ok
  ├─centos-root xfs               4fd04bf3-1aab-45f8-b262-20eb3bc4cf78   /
  ├─centos-swap swap              d6734505-00db-4093-a878-5078d2a3e90c   [SWAP]
  └─centos-home xfs               95de2ea1-ae13-4a6d-a978-a14aebd770b0   /home
[root@centos-app23 ~]#
[root@centos-app23 ~]# multipath -ll
[root@centos-app23 ~]#
[root@centos-app23 ~]# service multipathd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  multipathd.service
● multipathd.service - Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/multipathd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-08-06 05:25:25 AEST; 2h 42min ago
  Process: 153879 ExecReload=/sbin/multipathd reconfigure (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 152005 ExecStart=/sbin/multipathd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 152001 ExecStartPre=/sbin/multipath -A (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 151997 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe dm-multipath (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 152008 (multipathd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/multipathd.service
           └─152008 /sbin/multipathd

Aug 06 05:33:59 centos-app23 multipathd[152008]: reconfigure (operator)
Aug 06 06:44:18 centos-app23 multipathd[152008]: reconfigure (operator)
Aug 06 06:44:18 centos-app23 multipathd[153879]: ok
Aug 06 06:44:18 centos-app23 systemd[1]: Reloaded Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller.
Aug 06 07:23:50 centos-app23 multipathd[152008]: sdc: add path (uevent)
Aug 06 07:23:50 centos-app23 multipathd[152008]: mpathb: retry domap for addition of new path sdc
Aug 06 07:23:51 centos-app23 multipathd[152008]: mpathb: failed in domap for addition of new path sdc
Aug 06 07:23:51 centos-app23 multipathd[152008]: uevent trigger error
Aug 06 07:23:51 centos-app23 multipathd[152008]: dm-3: remove map (uevent)
Aug 06 07:23:51 centos-app23 multipathd[152008]: dm-3: remove map (uevent)
[root@centos-app23 ~]# multipathd -k
multipathd> show paths
hcil     dev dev_t pri dm_st chk_st dev_st  next_check
0:0:0:0  sda 8:0   1   undef ready  running orphan
15:0:0:0 sdb 8:16  1   undef ready  running orphan
16:0:0:0 sdc 8:32  1   undef ready  running orphan
multipathd>
multipathd> 
[root@centos-app23 ~]#
[root@centos-app23 ~]#
```

If I compare it with other similar server, I can see proper multipath output

```
[root@centos-app05 ~]# multipath -ll
mpatha (36000d310009899000000000000000056) dm-0 COMPELNT,Compellent Vol
size=1.0T features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=1 status=active
  |- 16:0:0:0 sdb 8:16 active ready running
  `- 17:0:0:0 sdc 8:32 active ready running
[root@centos-app05 ~]# lsblk -f
NAME              FSTYPE       LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda
└─sda1            ext3               0dd9a419-6752-473e-b49b-2138f6519827   /boot
sdb               mpath_member
└─mpatha
  ├─mpatha1       ext3               8100912c-c4f5-488b-8d9e-2e6c93d5e37e
  └─mpatha2       LVM2_member        ckoWGr-3kEW-NQRb-Ma18-OkXz-uxrb-HxemwY
    ├─centos-root xfs                54b2cd4a-dc96-484a-a204-839b0c1ba58a   /
    ├─centos-swap swap               894e6bbb-2c0d-43cf-93bf-a0d35bd5c97a   [SWAP]
    └─centos-home xfs                11f18806-30e4-4681-bac0-b15dd90cb3a1   /home
sdc               mpath_member
└─mpatha
  ├─mpatha1       ext3               8100912c-c4f5-488b-8d9e-2e6c93d5e37e
  └─mpatha2       LVM2_member        ckoWGr-3kEW-NQRb-Ma18-OkXz-uxrb-HxemwY
    ├─centos-root xfs                54b2cd4a-dc96-484a-a204-839b0c1ba58a   /
    ├─centos-swap swap               894e6bbb-2c0d-43cf-93bf-a0d35bd5c97a   [SWAP]
    └─centos-home xfs                11f18806-30e4-4681-bac0-b15dd90cb3a1   /home
[root@centos-app05 ~]#
```

Please advice, how to fix multipath. Thanks

Edit - I was able to solve it.
As far I remember,  I setup "obtain_device_list_from_udev = 0" and "use_lvmetad = 0" in /etc/lvm/lvm.conf and rebooted server and I was able to see /home.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?